# Kafka-connect sink task ignores file offset storage property

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm experiencing quite weird behavior working with Confluent JDBC connector. I'm pretty sure that it's not related to Confluent stack, but to Kafka-connect framework itself.

So, I define `offset.storage.file.filename` property as default `/tmp/connect.offsets` and run my sink connector. Obviously, I expect connector to persist offsets in the given file (it doesn't exist on file system, but it should be automatically created, right?). Documentation says:

> `offset.storage.file.filename`
>   The file to store connector offsets in. By storing offsets on disk, a standalone process can be stopped and started on a single node and resume where it previously left off.

But Kafka behaves in completely different manner.

1. It checks if the given file exists.
2. It it's not, Kafka just ignores it and persists offsets in Kafka topic.
3. If I create given file manually, reading fails anyway (EOFException) and offsets are being persisted in topic again.

Is it a bug or, more likely, I don't understand how to work with this configurations? I understand difference between two approaches to persist offsets and file storage is more convenient for my needs.

Answer (score 11):

The `offset.storage.file.filename` is only used in **source** connectors, in standalone mode. It is used to place a bookmark on the input data source and remember where it stopped reading it. The created file contains something like the file line number (for a file source) or a table row number (for jdbc source or databases in general).

When running Kafka Connect in distributed mode, this file is replaced by a Kafka topic named by default `connect-offsets` which should be replicated in order to tolerate failures.

As far as **sink** connectors are concerned, no matter which plugin or mode (standalone/distributed) is used, they all store where they last stopped reading their input topic in an internal topic named `__consumer_offsets` like any Kafka consumers. This allows to use traditional tools like `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` command-line tools to see how the much the sink connector is lagging.

The [Confluent Kafka replicator](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-replicator/docs/index.html), despite being a source connector, is probably an exception because it reads from a remote Kafka and may use a Kafka consumer, but only one cluster will maintain those original consumer group offsets.

I agree that the documentation is not clear, this setting is required whatever the connector type is (source or sink), but it is only used on by source connectors. The reason behind this design decision is that a single Kafka Connect worker (I mean a single JVM process) can run multiple connectors, potentially both source and sink connectors. Said differently, this setting is worker level setting, not a connector setting.

Answer (score 1):

The property `offset.storage.file.filename` only applies to workers of source connectors running in standalone mode. If you are seeing Kafka persist offsets in a Kafka topic for a source, you are running in distributed mode. You should be launching your connector with the provided script `connect-standalone`. There's a description of the different modes [here](http://docs.confluent.io/3.1.1/connect/userguide.html#standalone-vs-distributed). Instructions on running in the different modes are [here](http://docs.confluent.io/3.1.1/connect/userguide.html#running-workers).

Comment: I am running an Elasticsearch Kafka Connect sink in standalone mode and am seeing the same behaviour, i.e. the `offset.storage.file.filename` file is not created and the offsets appear to be being persisted elsewhere.

Comment: Sink connectors use Kafka consumer group functionality to store offsets. The offset file or topic for connect really only applies to source connectors in general.